# Can't clone the shared branch of a Git repository

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to develop an app for Firefox OS. After reading walls of text and guides in every form, I'm having hard time knowing where to start. So I figured out I should first get some sample codes from the Git repository.

For now, this part: https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/tree/v2.0/shared

As I'm new to Git (but experienced with SVN), I figured the command would be:

```
git clone https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/tree/v2.0/shared/
```

But I get the error:

> fatal: repository '`https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/tree/v2.0/shared`' not found

I tried with `git:` instead of `https:` but got the same error.

And I'm lost here. I'm pretty sure the reason is simple and I will be embarrassed to have asked the question, but still, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `shared` is a folder inside a repository, not a repository itself, you need to clone the whole gaia repository.

Comment: Thank you. So, there is no way I grab only this portion of this massive repository ? I have no use of the full branch.

Comment: it looks like you actually can do that, it's called a parse checkout : http://briancoyner.github.io/blog/2013/06/05/git-sparse-checkout/

Comment: Late edit : I'll try you solution, and if it fails I'll go for downloading the needed files one by one (can't vote your answer up sorry, not enough reputation).